# When i inspect the element ...i m getting my css style of bootstrap

Tags: html

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <tr>
            <td width="224" bgcolor="#DEECF5"> 
                <div align="right"><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                    <b>Address :</b>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#DEECF5"> 
                <input type="text" name="address"  class="form-control" value="<?php print $dataary['address'];?>">
                <br>
                <?php print $errors['address']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I inspect the element, I'm getting my CSS style of [Bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/form.less)
. Actually I  have to apply my CSS to `ttttt.css`, but when I inspect the textbox I'm getting to the `form.less`, now I want [this path](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/form.less) to be local file system. So can you also provide correct Bootstrap path example `<link href="css/bootstrap/form.less" rel="stylesheet"/>`. Please provide the bootstrap path for `forms.lss` and my textbox width for address is also large in size.

Comment: All files with you. So you better know what the location is I guess.

Comment: @TusharNiras okkk   ..whether i can give the path of bootstrap for less/forms.less in the code ?